# WebStorm HTTP Client inject variables from code

Tags: intellij-idea, httpclient, webstorm

How do inject variables to WebStorm **HTTP Client** from code, not separate `.env.json`?

#### Detail description.

Question about WebStorm, but actually it is related to HTTP Client plugin, which available in every JetBrains IDEA-based IDE. Someone calls it `Rest client`.

I want to create a dynamic demo for the class. But requests are based on the local setup.

I manage for now clean up the usual configurations, that do not use additional variables. Everything has come from the `.env` file and working as expected. But *HTTP Client* is like a completely separate program inside the IDE. It does not integrate with a project in any shape or form. It does not share run configuration. It does not use shell environment vars. Everyone in class needs to copy-paste the same info into a project and HTTP Client.

**For example**. Everyone in class has `.env` file where he did set-up variable `API-URL="localhost:8084"` and port is different. This is how their local rest server is set up.

Now, I am sharing `example.rest` with everyone. For example:

```http
### RestAPI
GET https://{{api_url}}
```

They *should* have ability to run it and get result. Only option I have - to create `http-client.env.json` with

```json
{
  "dev": {
    "api_url": "{{some public access url}}"
  },
  "local": {
    "api_url": "localhost:8084"
  }
}
```

And now each student need to change this `env.json` file for local setup.

**Problem** - Duplicating vars between different files. Manual goverment of git changes for this file.

So, is there any way how to share data between a project and HTTP Client?

Thank you for your ideas!

Read documentation:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/exploring-http-syntax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to JetBrains staff, this is impossible and was done on purpose.

Their current vision - is that HTTP Client **is** a separate application and they avoid any further integration with main IDEs.

Links:

- Discussion with staff - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4813628.
- Company vision as a separate app - https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/12/http-client-cli-run-requests-and-tests-on-ci/

**PS**
As the only **possible solution** for this moment - add popularity to JetBrains issue to introduce this kind of functionality - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-314198/Allow-project-environment-injection-to-HTTP-Client